# Quickbooks online doing Incorrect Round off of "Total" value for Sales Receipt

Tags: quickbooks-online

I am currently developing an integration between Linnworks and QuickBooks.

When I attempt to submit processed "Order" details to QuickBooks Online via API, I encounter unexpected behavior from QBO.

Even though the data retrieved from Linnworks in my connector is exactly the same as what I am sending to the QBO API, discrepancies are observed in multiple sales receipts.

**Example No 1:**

**Description:** All the values (Sub-total, Discount & Tax) are correct. But the **Total** is decreasing by .01 penny.

**Expected Total:** 339.99

**Current Total:** 339.98

.

**Example No 2 :**

**Description:** The subtotal matches the data present in Linnworks and posted by our integration. However, there is an automatic increment of .01 in the "Total" value

**Expected Total:** 279.99

**Current Total:** 280.00

[image: QuickBooks screenshot attached]